# Ordering rows and then getting a particular 10 rows from that set

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a database table that holds the number of points a user has earned in a game, that looks like this:

> id points
>   1  1000
>   2  300
>   3  600
>   4  900
>   etc

I want to be able to get just the rows with the 50th to 59th most points. It's ok if more than one query is needed. I'm using PHP and MySQL. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$query = "SELECT *
          FROM table_name
          ORDER BY points DESC
          LIMIT 49,10";

$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  // Do stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from table order by points desc limit 49,10
```

Comment: +1 for remembering that it is 49, not 50 that you want to get result number 50 (unlike myself).

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
select id,points from table order by points desc limit 49,10;
```